# Call parent controllers' function from directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89AYX/48/)

I have a ng-click within a directive named `ball`.  I am trying to call `MainCtrl`'s function `test()` and alert the value of `ng-repeat's alignment` of ball.
Why cant i recognize the MainCtrl's test function?
    var $scope;
    var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.project = {"name":"sup"};

    $scope.test = function(value) {
        alert(value);   
    }
    $scope.test2 = function(value) {
        alert('yo'+value);   
    }

}).directive('ball', function () {
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            scope: {
                'test': '&test'
            },
            template: '<div class="alignment-box" ng-repeat="alignment in [0,1,2,3,4]" ng-click="test(alignment)" val="{{alignment}}">{{alignment}}</div>'

        };
    });
```

**html**

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
   <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
       {{project}}
       <ball></ball>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `test()` method from the controller into the directive...

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
   <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
       {{project}}
       <ball test="test"></ball>
   </div>
</div>
```

Change `&` to `=` in directive:

```
scope: {
    'test': '=test'
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/89AYX/49/**

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the controller in your directive as:
    controller: 'MainCtrl'

so the code for your directive should look like:

```
return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {
        'test': '&test'
    },
    template: '<div class="alignment-box" ng-repeat="alignment in [0,1,2,3,4]" ng-click="test(alignment)" val="{{alignment}}">{{alignment}}</div>',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'

};
```

Comment: This works but it couples the directive to the controller. Also should remove `'test': '&test'` from the isolated scope as that's no longer needed if referencing the controller directly.

Answer (score 1):

the one way is to not isolate a directive scope...just remove the scope object from directive.

Another way is to implement an angular service and put a common method there, inject this service wherever you need it and in the directive call function that will be insight isolated scope and there call a function from directive